# Oracle : copy result of SQL statement to clipboard

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g

I need to copy result from SQL to clipboard - is this possible?

I need copy of qty to clipboard.

My code:

```
declare qty NUMBER;
        part_no varchar(16);

begin
    qty := (select qty from part_stock where part_no='012345');

    if qty > 0 then
        error_sys.Appl_General('', 'Item_no is on stock');
    else 
        error_sys.Appl_General('', 'Item_no is not on stock');
    end if;
end;
```

Thank you

Comment: Copy what result, to which clipboard, from which client, in what kind of environment? You’ve shown a PL/SQL block which includes some SQL. It really isn’t clear what you’re trying to do.

Comment: Hello, i need result of (select qty from part_stock where part_no='012345') in clipboard. I don't know if it's possible by sql code to copy this result.

Comment: PL/SQL runs within the database on the server and has no access to any clipboard.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using PLSQL developer, on an SQL window, this icon will let you copy results to the clipboard, in several different formats.
[image]